# Resizing image using slider in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, resize, slider

Maybe a stupid question but I inherited the job of developing an image editor which allows the user to add images and then either save what is on the canvas, or save the project's elements etc. to a server and DB to come back to it later. The attributes such as image width and height are sent and called back on load so the image is loaded back where it was on the canvas.

Part of the functionality is to re-size images. I am doing this with a slider which has a binding to the image width. The image gets smaller proportionally when I use the slider but the value of the image height nor the image actual height won't change which causes problems when the project is loaded again as the height stored in the db is incorrect.

The XAML for the slider area:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Width:" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="24" Margin="3" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="px" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3,0,0,0" />

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Height:" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                    <TextBox x:Name="txtImageHeight" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Height, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="24" Margin="3" />
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="px" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="3,0,0,0" />

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Size:" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    <Slider Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Minimum="0" SmallChange=".01" LargeChange=".10" Maximum="{Binding Path=MaxWidth}"
                                        Value="{Binding Path=Width, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ValueChanged="Slider_ValueChanged" />
```

The value in the Height text box obviously doesn't change as I want either.

And the code:

```
private void AddImageElement(object param)
    {
        bool? gotImage;
        string fileName;
        BitmapImage imageSource = GetImageFromLocalMachine(out gotImage, out fileName);

        if (gotImage == true)
        {
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Name = fileName;
            image.Source = imageSource;
            image.Height = imageSource.PixelHeight;
            image.Width = imageSource.PixelWidth;
            image.MaxHeight = imageSource.PixelHeight;
            image.MaxWidth = imageSource.PixelWidth;
            image.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
            image.Tag = null;

            AddDraggingBehavior(image);
            image.MouseLeftButtonUp += element_MouseLeftButtonUp;

            this.Elements.Add(image);
            numberOfElements++;

            this.SelectedElement = image;
            this.SelectedImageElement = image;
        }
    }
```

How do I get the height value to reflect the height that the image is rendered as?

I'm completely new to Silverlight and .NET so maybe I'm missing something obvious

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Silverlight has some known insufficiencies when it comes to resize bindings. I built a viewer a while ago with scaling functionality which I wanted to bind to a slider, and I found that there are some little helper tools required. I use the `LayoutTransformer` from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), and the [`AnimationMediator` from one of the Toolkit developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/04/10/a-bit-more-er-than-meets-the-eye-easily-animate-and-update-layouttransformer-with-animationmediator.aspx).

With the `LayoutTransformer` you can set its content to anything, not just images, and apply any transformation with it, and as opposed to the usual `RenderTransform`, it will affect layout and actual sizes. My elements are not in a `Canvas` though, so I don't know how it will behave in your scenario and if you can use it, but maybe this sample can still be of help for you.

```
<Grid>
    <fs:AnimationMediator x:Name="ScaleXMediator" LayoutTransformer="{Binding ElementName=LayoutTransformer}" AnimationValue="{Binding ScaleX, ElementName=ScaleTransform, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <fs:AnimationMediator x:Name="ScaleYMediator" LayoutTransformer="{Binding ElementName=LayoutTransformer}" AnimationValue="{Binding ScaleY, ElementName=ScaleTransform, Mode=TwoWay}" />

    <tkt:LayoutTransformer x:Name="LayoutTransformer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <tkt:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform" />
        </tkt:LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>

        <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="mysource.png" Width="600" Height="800" />
    </tkt:LayoutTransformer>
</Grid>
```

Because I won't go into MultiBinding here, you'll additionally have to manually handle the `Slider`'s value changed event and then set the `AnimationValue`s of `ScaleXMediator` and `ScaleYMediator` appropriately.

Hope it helps!

Comment: As I needed my image to constrain proportions anyway, I ended up just getting the initial ratio between height and width of the image and I have a text changed event handler on the width that changes the height value when the width is changed with the slider based on keeping that same ratio. Kind of a butchering of an attempt but it seems to work fine. Anyone see any huge problems with the way I've done it?